# Sharing Hibernate Search index

Tags: indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to use Hibernate Search in my application; the app contains several modules accessing the search index:

- one writer/reader module
- two or three read-only modules

(the modules will reside on the same physical machine)

Can this be done? Is it enough, if the same index directory is shared between the modules? Are there any performance penalties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are only performance penalties when you need multiple applications on the same machine to *write*.

Since in your case only one app will be writing, you can get good performance by allowing that application to use "exclusive mode", and the other applications to read only.

Exclusive mode is the default since version 5.0, so no configuration change is needed for the writer/reader application.

The other applications need to be configured to not open an IndexWriter at bootstrap, which would have them acquire the index writing lock.

Just set this property:

```
hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use = false
```

One limitation: you can not use the Near-real-time IndexManager described in [section 3.2.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#_near_real_time), as the writes would not be flushed to disk on each write operation, so the other applications would not see the latest changes.

Comment: Thank you! Approximatly how big will this delay be? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: When using NRT the delay is not controlled by time, but by the buffers being full. So that's not very practical, that's why I suggested to not enable NRT. Even the default settings (non-NRT) give pretty good performance.